# $F \subseteq \mathbb R$ be a closed set, $y \in \mathbb R$, define $F_y=\{x \in F~:~x+y \leq 2\}$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $F \subseteq \mathbb R$ be a closed set, $y \in \mathbb R$, define $F_y=\{x \in F~:~x+y \leq 2\}$, then can $F_y$ be closed in $\mathbb R$ ?

Can we take the sequential definition?, If $x_n \in F_y$ for all $n \in \mathbb N$ such that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty }x_n=x$, then we have $x_n \leq 2-y$ for all $n \in \mathbb N$........

Comment: Well, since $y\in\mathbb R$ is arbitrary, so is $2-y$. As such, you can simplify the problem by defining $F_y=\{x\in F\;:\;x\leq y\}$. Also, it's just easier noting that if we let $\mathbb R_y=\{x\in\mathbb R\;:\;x\leq y\}$, which is clearly closed and $F_y=\mathbb R_y\cap F$, and the intersection of 2 closed sets is closed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$F_y =F\cap (-\infty,2-y\mkern1.5mu]$$
is the intersection of two closed sets…